# pthread_create does not execute properly

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, debugging, posix

I am learning about multi-thread programs and am expecting the following snippet of code to be an infinite loop of printing "`foo"` instead nothing happens

Expectations :

> foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo

Reality :

> 

It is as though the thread is not even being created , what am i  doing wrong ??? How do  i create a thread which will execute whatever function is assigned to it

**Source code**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void* print(void*);

struct threadInfo
{

    int threadID;
    int threadNo;

};

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    bool cont = false;
    int i = 1;
    int max = 3;

    while ( cont == false )
    {
        if ( i <= max )
        {
            threadInfo t_info;
            t_info.threadID = i ;
            t_info.threadNo = i ;
            pthread_create(&thread[i-1],NULL,print,(void*)&t_info);

            i++;
        }
    }   





}

void* print(void* arg)
{
  std::cout << "Foo" ; 
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The following piece of code is compiled on Ubuntu command line with the following command

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lpthread
```

Comment: check return value of phread_create, it's bad habit to not check it

Comment: I guess your threads not flushing their output... But even so, you'll only get FooFooFoo, i.e. one Foo per thread

Answer (score 2):

The threads are created, but before they could run, the main thread exits, and your program terminates (it's also UB). You have to wait for your threads: [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)

The `while ( cont == false )` is not needed.

Comment: Is the main thread really exiting? Isn't it in an infinite loop?

Comment: @erenon its a infinite loop , i dont see how the main thread exits before the sub thread

Answer (score 1):

There nothing printed because the output buffers are not *flushed*.

In the `print` function, do e.g.

```
std::cout << "Foo" << std::flush;
```

Comment: Why must i flush the output buffer ?? Why does the output of foo stop after 3 times , should it be infinite ??

Comment: @Computernerd Because it's not done automatically. If the buffer is not flushed, nothing is actually printed, it's just stored in the memory buffer.

Comment: how come in a normal program , i can just cout and its automatically flushed

Comment: @Computernerd The buffers are flushed when the file object is closed, like when a program is exiting. If you're not exiting your program, there is no automatic flushing. And of course the buffers are flushed when they overflow, but since the buffer may be arbitrarily large you can't know when that will happen.

Answer (score 1):

My oh my... Where to start ?

The reason why you don't see a thing has been given by Joachim Pileborg: the threads are created all right and do their job, but since your main program never exits and nobody ever outputs a line feed, the line-buffered output is never flushed.

Your main program is wasting CPU looping on a flag that will never be changed. Trying to synchronize threads with flags is extremely bad, despite the stupid new C++11 extensions that make atomic variables the alpha and omega of thread programming.
You must use some kind of synchro to wait for thread terminations. The most usual mechanism is `pthread_join`.

Passing the same instance of parameters to each instance of your thread creates a perfect race condition. You have no guarantee the thread will read the parameters in your intended order (i.e. before the main loop changes them to prepare for the next thread launch). You should pass each thread its own private instance of `t_info` (or setup some kind of synchronization mechanism over this structure).

Even after fixing all these problems, you should expect only 3 "Foo" since each thread exits after a single print.

And since you don't serialize the `cout` accesses (i.e. you don't protect them with some kind of synchro object like a mutex), it is possible the outputs of your various threads will be mixed at random (i.e. you could see something like "FoFFooooo").

Comment: your `if ( i <= max )` test prevents the creation of more than 3 threads.

Comment: I made i a global variable and added i-- inside the print function , the new program prints foo 200 times but it is still not infinite

Comment: Here again you are creating a race condition between your main program and your threads by incrementing/decrementing an unprotected counter. You have to understand flags and counters are NOT the solution to share information between tasks, let alone control their synchronization.

Comment: How do i use mutex to control the counter to ensure that there will be an infinite loop of print function

Comment: Well it's time to open a textbook and see what synchronization objects are all about. It's not a simple thing to be explained in a couple of sentences. It requires both theoretical background and a lot of practice to master.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread probably ends (and tremrinates all other thread with this) before any other thread has printed out anything.

To fix this either make the main thread join loopig around (`pthread_join()` for all thread-ids created) on all other thread before ending, or end the main thread using `pthread_exit()`.

---

Also passing the address of the **same** instance of `struct threadInfo` the each tread (that is: `(void*)&t_info`) most probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with pthreads. If you want to ensure that sequence in the output, you need to enclose the print out line with a lock and a flush, so that you enforce that,

```
1. A thread only finishes once the message has actually been printed out
2. Threads wait for each other so that no two threads write to the output at the same time
```